# Python: Cat file to self within script

Tags: python, bash

Suppose I have a python script that I would like to be able to process a file as an input:

```
./script.py input_file.txt
```

However, I would also like to run bash commands like `sort` on the file before it gets parsed by the script.

Is there a way to internally call bash commands and pass the output to stdin?

Basically, the only thing that is changing is:

```
cat file | sort | ./script.py

# changes to: 

./script.py --input_file file
```

And within the `script.py` I might run:

```
import some_lib as sl


sl.bash(cat args.input_file | sort | this script's stdin buffer)

...
    for line in stdin:
        ...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not just `./script.py <(sort input_file.txt)`?

Comment: (Note that letting `sort` directly access the input file can be significantly more efficient with large inputs than forcing it to read the output from `cat` through a FIFO; giving it a direct file handle means it can split into threads, each handling a subset of the file, and then use a merge sort to combine their outputs; by contrast, a FIFO can only be read once, front-to-back).

Comment: ...and btw, is there a reason you aren't using, say, `for line in sorted(sys.stdin):` and not bothering with shell tools at all?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the point is that I am dealing with, say, 250 gig files. I am trying to make the code super easy to use.  I want to be able to pipe things into the code.  The cat statement is just there for illustrative purposes.  In actuality, I might use parallel, zcat, and do some other things before I sort.

Comment: I'm still not sold on needing a shell for any of that. Python has its own gzip library; Python has its own management tools for parallel processing (see the `multiprocessing` library); etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, there is: ideally, this tool can take an optional argument (input file) or have content piped directly into it.  So, yes this is syntactical sugar.  But, it would significantly reduce complexity if I could maintain everything inside a python script...and still hold onto the low memory overhead of stdinput

Comment: (now, granted, I'm the grumpy person over here who considers GNU parallel an abominable mess of unreadable perl, but...)

Comment: "low memory overhead of stdin" -- it's only low-overhead if you're writing your shell scripts intelligently. Using `cat | sort` instead of feeding `sort` a live FD is just the sort of thing that blows your overhead, even if it's not internal to the shell (and will often be worked around by `sort` creating temporary files).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this is about limiting memory use.  Nothing else. I am not aware of a way to sort a file in python without loading it into memory.  Bash has this ability. Python can read through the file line by line.

Comment: @123 basically, I am trying to avoid shell scripts, but sort an extremely large file before reading only a fraction of it with a python script. In order to do that, I need to know the file size in python... but I am trying to keep it as simple for the user as possible--so they can just do `./script.py file` rather than: sort the file, pipe it into the script, and tell the script how big it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).
That's a python 2 link. If you're using 3, look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).